# How to resize the height of the subgrid in dynamics crm forms?

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm, subgrid

After spending the whole day, I am posting the following question.

I have follow [this](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog.aspx/paul-nieuwelaars-blog/2012/05/17/dynamics_crm_2011_sub_grids_with_more_rows_and_scroll_bar) for showing more records in sub-grid of dynamics CRM. This help me a lot. but my question is that the user will be able to see only 1 or two records and for other records he must have to use scroll-er? Is there any mean to do so using .js library or any other steps are there?

Your kind help and suggestion will encourage me a lot.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Maximum number or rows determines how many records are displayed without needing to scroll.  So If you set the maximum number of rows to 6 and check "Automatically expand" then it will show a grid with 6 rows visible and the remaining rows accessible by scrolling.